# Chain of responsibility pattern vs Iterating over a list of strategies

Tags: design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

How does a CoR pattern compare to implementing the items in the chain as a list and having a single orchestrator class try the items in this list sequentially?

Which is a better approach?

Example:

```
Class A implements NodeInAChain{

NodeInAChain nextNode;

public Result doWork(Request request){
// Some logic
if(logicSuccessful) {
 return;
else
 nextNode.doWork(request);
}
}
```

Vs

```
Class ChainOrchestrator {

List<NodeInAChain> nodeList;

public Result doWork(Request request){
foreach(node : nodeList) {
 if(node.doWork(request) == 'success'){
   break;
 } 
}
return result;
}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of chain-of-responsibility vs. lists of classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055383/what-are-the-advantages-of-chain-of-responsibility-vs-lists-of-classes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Chain of Responsibility pattern just an overkill ? A List of Handlers can accomplish the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979891/is-chain-of-responsibility-pattern-just-an-overkill-a-list-of-handlers-can-acc)