# i am getting error while connecting java databas

Tags: java

error i am getting

Error loading MySQL driver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Javaconnect {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lol", "root", "lol@9056");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading MySQL driver: " + e);
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Established connection");
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more information - how have you *tried* to make the MySQL driver available? How are you running your code, what's your classpath etc?

Comment: There is no jdbc driver in your classpath. If you use javac and java commands to execute code, you need to explicitly point out the jdbc driver: `javac -cp xxx/yyy.jar`, where xxx is the directory and yyy.jar is the name of the driver.If you use ide, I can't answer, there are a lot of configurations, I don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

JDBC driver is loaded by `DriverManager` dynamically in runtime, based on the analysis of the connection string, using some modified version of the chain of responsibility design pattern or just a list of registered drivers, it doesn't matter (see an interesting discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1055383/2886891)). The [`getConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)) method asks all the registered drivers if they are able to create a connection for the specified string, and first who does it returns the connection.

```java
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lol", "root", "lol@9056");
```

If you had only that code, you would get a different exception or maybe just `null`, telling that the `DriverManager` didn't find any suitable driver.

However, your code contains first

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

By calling the [`forName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) first, you are asking via [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to get the class object. "Reflection" means that you are not using the compiler to get the class object, such as `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class` would do, but you are passing only a `String` parameter, meaning that the **code is still compilable** even if the class is not accessible at the compile time. And then **at runtime** you get the `ClassNotFoundException` exception exactly how the documentation states.

You are not using the return value of the method, but still you get the exception, so your call serves rather like a runtime test for the presence of the class.

**To fix the error**, you need your program to have the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` available during runtime.

You have multiple techniques for it. You may do it directly by setting the classpath command line parameter of the program and telling it where the class is on your disk. Or you may do it in your IDE (IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, ... whatever you use) via adding the dependency to the library containing the missing JDBC driver.

However, I **strongly recommend** you to [learn using Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven) (or Gradle) to handle it automatically for you. Then you may use these e.g. simple tutorial for JDBC: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc

Your learning investment to Maven will pay back very much, do it!